# Calling one event method from another event method with passing a parameter

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am trying to call one EventHandler method from another. For example, I would like to link Logout button with form exit, so I have this code:

```
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Bla, bla?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

and I want to call it from this event:

```
private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    FormMain_FormClosing(null, 'not sure what goes here');
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are calling `FormMain_FormClosing` method? I cannot think of any circumstance where you would need to call this method. It is automatically called when the form wants to close, so you probably should be calling `Close()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the event and asking for confirmation are seperate things:

```
private static bool UserConfirmedToLogout() 
{
    return MessageBox.Show("Bla, bla?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK;
}

private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !UserConfirmedToLogout();
}

private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Close();
}
```

When Close() is called, the FormClosing event is fired too.

Comment: This answer is most appropriate because it avoids the bad practice of calling an event handler from another handler.  If the same code needs to be run from both handlers, it should be extracted out into another method.  This answer bypasses this bad practice with a clean solution for the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    FormMain_FormClosing(null, null);
}
```

or

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1_FormClosing(
        null, 
        new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.UserClosing, false));
}
```

Even if my answer cover how to link event handlers part, this particular solution leads you to a problem: form won't close clicking button.
Correct solution is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: That won't make the Form close. If he would call `Close()` from `btnLogOut_Click` then that would also trigger the `Form.Closing` event.

Comment: @SuperOli: yes, you're right. But OP is asking how to link an EventHandler to another... and my answer cover that part. I will edit my answer